# C# Parameters for Returning a Private Variable From a Public Method

Tags: c#

Whereas in VB standard programming practice with classes is to set a private variable directly and only access it through a public method to return it's value this doesn't seem to work. Or maybe my issue is in how I handle parameters and arguments.

I would extremely appreciate someone could resolve this issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Program
{
class Program
{

    private string name;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetName();
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " & ReturnName());
    }
    private static void SetName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static string ReturnName(string name)
    {
        return name;
    }
}
}
```

Errors:

[image: Screenshot of Problem]

Comment: Those variables are completely unrelated except for their name (no pun intended).

Comment: The first `name` ( `private string name;`) is a field of class Program. To access it, you'd need an *instance* of that class. `string name` in `SetName()` is a *local* variable that goes out of scope when the function returns. It has nothing to do with the first one whatsoever. `ReturnName` will return whatever the parameter called `name` is...

Comment: Please don't post errors as screenshot, but as text. You can copy them from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have declared a class level variable 'name', you can initialize it once in the class scope and you can pass it to 'ReturnName' function as a parameter.

You don't need 'ReturnName' function at all. I have modified it like, 'SetName' to 'GetName' which returns the name where the user inputs. You can directly print in the main function like below,

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name = GetName();
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
    }


    private static string GetName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        return name;
    }
```

Comment: Since when are there "global" variables in C#? Or in other words: What is your definition of "global" ?

Comment: This code works thanks, but the variable name is now accessible from anywhere which I don't want. I only want the variable accessible from the function.

Comment: @MaxGoddard I have made the variable name completely local. You don't want to class level variable to get user input. As you can see the code 'GetName' returns the user input and returns it. In the main function, it simply prints the returned name and scope of the variable 'name' is just inside the main function

Answer (score 3):

You are using distinct variables. The only thing these variables share is their name. This code will work:

```
private static string name;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SetName();
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + ReturnName());
}

private static void SetName()
{
    Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
}

public static string ReturnName()
{
    return name;
}
```

A little better would be to return the value from the `SetName` method and reuse that within the method scope, but that is just my opinion:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name = AskName();
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {name}.");
}

private static string AskName()
{
    Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I would use this method (no pun) if I was using it to get a one time choice but as I want to access name later I want to store it into a variable.

Comment: The first code block takes care of that. @MaxGoddard

Answer (score 1):

The concept that you want is called in C# a property.

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

It automatically declares a field in your class and the `get` `set` methods that wrap it so you do not have to write them. But you can if you want:

```
public string Name 
{
    get {return _name;}
    set {_name = value;}
}

string _name;
```

Your code does not work because you are creating local variables inside your methods. To correct it make `static` consistent and remove variables:

```
private static string name;

private static void SetName()
{
    Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
}
public static string ReturnName()
{
    return name;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with variables? Not everything has to be a property.

Comment: what's the point in assigning local variable and doing nothing with it, or returning the parameter in your method?  The first paragraph of the question describes encapsulation the `practice` to use and get set methods - properties. @PatrickHofman

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read about scoping. In `SetName()` you declare a local variable (only accessible in `SetName()`) named `name`. However, this is in no way connected to the instance variable `name` you declared at the beginning of the class.

Also, string concatenation in C# is done with `+`, not with `&`.

Comment: It's not global.

Comment: @Fildor: You're right, it's an instance variable, not a global variable.